# Visual Basic form works on SQL Server machine but not on local machine

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, forms, visual-studio

I have a Visual basic form with buttons which upload various excel spreadsheets to a SQL database. The form works perfectly fine when the form is loaded/used on the same machine where the SQL Database is hosted. However when I copy the form to my local machine, I keep getting the same error

[image: Insert Records Error]

I know there is probably something obvious I am missing however if someone could please assist it would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably didn't configure connection to DB from your local machine. Where's the SQL server, in same network, on web...? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: It sounds like your configuration needs to be changed when you aren't on the same machine. It probably can't find the database, and that's why you're getting a null pointer to the database.

Comment: SQL Server is in the same network, hosted on our server machine. DBMS is SQL Server 2017. I can connect to the SQL Server in every other way from my machine.

Comment: The exception suggests you are using the OleDb provider for Sql Server.  Why aren't you using the native Sql provider?